# Problema con `glob` en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola que tal a todos tengo un problema con `glob` y es que no me esta dando los archivos de manera ordenada, es un sencillo código:

```
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\/*.jpg")
filenames.sort()
```

Lo que me da de salida es:

```
['C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face1.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face10.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face11.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face12.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face13.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face14.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face15.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face16.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face17.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face18.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face19.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face2.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face20.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face3.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face4.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face5.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face6.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face7.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face8.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face9.jpg']
```

La salida que me gustaría tener es:

```
['C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face1.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face2.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face3.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face4.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face5.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face6.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face7.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face8.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face9.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face10.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face11.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face12.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face13.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face14.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face15.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face16.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face17.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face18.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face19.jpg',
 'C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\face20.jpg']
```

No se porque no me está ordenando, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Los archivo estan ordenados de forma natural.

Comment: @eyllanesc en la carpeta los tengo ordenados de esa manera en la carpeta.

Comment: Podrias indicar que salida deseas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python cuando ordena string esta usando [Natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order), por lo cual genera ese orden, se puede dar un criterio de comparación adecuado para ello usamos la función sorted:

```
import glob
import os
import re

def fun(elem):
    head, tail = os.path.split(elem)
    number = int(re.findall(r'\d+', tail)[0])
    return number

filenames = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\LuisMiguel\\Downloads\\Faces\\/*.jpg")
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=fun)
print(filenames)
```

la función fun() es pasada como parámetro key, este es el valor que es usado para comparar, entonces la tarea de fun() es obtener el digito que acompaña a .jpg, para ello usamos split() que separa y nos da el nombre de la carpeta y el nombre del archivo, usamos este último, pero como queremos extraer el número una opción seria usar expresiones regulares.

Otra opción para obtener el número es simplemente eliminar "face" y ".jpg":

```
def fun(elem):
    head, tail = os.path.split(elem)
    number = int(tail[4:-4])
    return number
```