# Introducir fotos por antiguedad en Python mediante la fecha incluida en su nombre

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, imagen

Tengo muchas imágenes tal que:
`IR108_METEOSAT6-MVIRI-MTP15-NA-NA-20010104000000.png` y necesito algo (como la librería de datatime) para poder introducirlas en el programa de forma progresiva por antiguedad.

El número de cada imagen corresponde a año, mes, día, hora, minuto y segundo. He pensado en crear una variable para cada cosa y que al cabo de pasar una foto se sume un número, al llegar a 31 se ponga a 0... pero me parece un suplicio.

A demás tengo un problema y es que no tengo fotos de todos los días, por lo tanto, necesito algo que simplemente introdzca imágenes en el programa por antiguedad.

He pensado en un bucle de Image.open("IR108_METEOSAT6-MVIRI-MTP15-NA-NA-" + str(FECHA) + ".png"). la cuestión está en hacer que FECHA se vaya modificando...

```
path = "C:/Users/Joan/Desktop/Photos"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
print(dirs)
```

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes las imagenes? ¿Un directorio con subdirectorios? ¿Varios directorios separados?

Comment: Todas las imágenes están en una misma carpeta, entonces supongo que eso no resulta ser un problema. Por lo que tengo entendido, si el programa está dentro de esta misma carpeta con las imágenes no necesito decir en qué ubicación exaca se ubican... aún así, no estoy seguro. Gracias. @CandidMoe

Comment: La solución es: crear una lista con todos los nombres de archivos (`listdir`) y ordenarlos usando una función que extraiga la fecha del nombre de archivo (`sorted(lista,key=funcion)`. Intentalo. Publica tu código si te quedas entrampado.

Comment: @CandidMoe He actualizado la pregunta, con lo que he puesto ahora he conseguido una lista con el nombre de las imágenes. ¿Como haces para ordenar la lista por lo que he dicho? ¿Hay que crear una función?

Comment: Ahora revisa esta pregunta, que es esencialmente igual a la tuya: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121059/problema-con-glob-en-python/121065#121065

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con \`glob\` en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121059/problema-con-glob-en-python)

Comment: En mi caso la función que tengo que usar es la misma? Veo que esta otra persona usa algo llamado glob...

Comment: `listdir` lista el contenido del directorio; `glob` lista además los subdirectorios recursivamente. Cualquiera te sirve.

Comment: Al usar la misma función se me desordena aún más... @CandidMoe